# How to display most recent record added to database at the bottom in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want display the record in descending order and by using `orderBy` it is working, but it is displaying in top( i need to view records like in chat most recent at bottom, but now i am getting as mail most recent top) can any one help me.

```
$data = DB::table("chatbox")
                  ->where('dept_name',Session::get('dept_name'))

                  ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                  ->get();
```

Comment: Show us some code maybe?

Comment: i am doing like that @Insax

Comment: please try with this `->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')`

Comment: i need to display like chat application most recent message at bottom @Kirit

Comment: @Hemanth please be more specific by giving example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = DB::table("chatbox")
              ->where('dept_name',Session::get('dept_name'))

              ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
              ->get();
```

just change desc to ASC

Comment: i know that but i need to display most recent record at bottom(eg: like whatsapp if we scroll only it will go to previous messages like that i need to display). Most recent should be visible at bottom

Comment: For example consider any chat the most recent is at bottom and visible

Comment: Man... either you explain yourself like a closed book, or we are dense. If you get the results in the inverse order you need, just invert it with the orderBy function as Kuldeep showed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it like messaging app style (last added record at the bottom), you could do this:

1. Make sure you know how many records you want to show at one page, for example, 10 records
2. Do your query as usual, to pull the last 10 records you want to show (sort by created_at, desc)
3. Now you should have 10 latest records on hand. In your view, you do an ascending sort on the created_at, then render them. So this will cause oldest record on top, and latest record at bottom.

Additionally:

- Whenever there is a new record comes in, you can just append it into the list.
- If the user need more data (pull down or something), you fetch 10 more records, and at your view, sort all records ascending, and render it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the collection after getting the results:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['name' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
    ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150], ]);

$sorted = $collection->sortBy('price');

$sorted->values()->all();

$data = DB::table("chatbox")
                  ->where('dept_name',Session::get('dept_name'))
                  ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                  ->paginate(20);

$sorted = $data->sortBy('created_at');

$sorted->values()->all();
```

I did not test it but you might give it a try.

Comment: And why a `orderBy` and `sortBy` That isn't needed

Comment: orderBy orders the database query (descending in this case - so the latest messages will be on the first page). sortBy sorts the collection (ascending in this case - so the latest message will be at the bottom) (after getting the database results).

Comment: And it make some difference in this case? You can use `desc` in the query too or `sortByDesc`. Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: You may have 100000 messages. At the database level you need to order the query DESC and LIMIT to 10 to take the latest 10 messages. The user wants to have the last message to the bottom so you need to reorder that 10 messages ASC to achieve that. It is a 2 step process, at least my solution.

Comment: You are absolut right, I hadn't a coffee before sending my comment ;) Sorry